# Amplify CLI: An error occured during the push operation: Cannot read property 'extensions' of null

Tags: aws-amplify-cli

Is there a way to resolve this issue without deleting the project's amplify directory and beginning from scratch?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Clone Git repository containing an Amplify CLI project
2. Update Node version from 8.16.1 to 10.17.0 (`nvm install 10.17`)
3. Update Amplify CLI version from 1.8.2 to 4.2.0 (`npm i -g @aws-amplify/cli@4.2.0`)
4. Initialize Amplify (`amplify init` and choose existing environment)
5. Deploy using Amplify CLI (`amplify push`)

Resulting error:

✖ An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud

Cannot read property 'extensions' of null
An error occured during the push operation: Cannot read property 'extensions' of null

Answer (score 1):

A project root file named `.graphqlconfig.yml` was causing the error:

```
projects:
  myappname:
    schemaPath: src/graphql/schema.json
    excludes:
      - ./amplify/**
    extensions:
      amplify:
        graphQLApiId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      endpoints:
        prod: >-
          https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql
```

in our case, we installed Node version 12.13.1, used Amplify CLI version 4.4.0, and deleted the file. Then `amplify push` succeeded.